# MSDEPLOY_RENAME_LOCKED_FILES equivalent for devops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Does anyone know the MSDEPLOY_RENAME_LOCKED_FILES (used in azure) equivalent in devops?  I want to set this when pipeline runs in devops to publish to IIS local server.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Currently, this method only supports Azure Web APP service. This option is used to set the Azure App settings(cloud).

It does not apply to IIS local server(on-prem). As far as I know, there is no work around for this.

[image]

Comment: Hi thank you for your suggestion but this would not work.  I am using devops.  I am looking for the MSDEPLOY_RENAME_LOCKED_FILES (used in azure) equivalent in devops.